# Hashed client secrets for the client credentials OAuth 2 flow in Apache CXF

Tags: oauth-2.0, cxf

I'm attempting to implement the Client Credentials flow of OAuth 2.0 to secure a RESTful service, using Apache CXF (version 2.7.12).

My only client (for now) will be trusted to keep the key and secret confidential - I'm aware of the considerations around that.

My question is how I should store the client secret on the authorisation server. In my mind, the 'client secret' is effectively a password, and thus should be salted and hashed. However, CXF's AccessTokenService, which does the comparison between the stored secret and the value passed in on the request, only does a String.equals() comparison, and doesn't seem to give me any hook where I can provide a different mechanism.

This means that I would need to store the client secret in plain text in order to compare it against the plain text value from the request, without a slightly hacky alternative.

Am I missing some obvious functionality that would let me hash the incoming value before the comparison, or am I being overly-cautious with the client secret? Maybe I'm wrong to treat it like a password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sort-of answer, for people encountering this question in the future.

My approach was to create a very simple filter (as described here: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-filters.html), which manually creates a SecurityContext (https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/security/SecurityContext.html), and adds it to the Message as it passes through the Filter.

This means that as the flow continues on to CXF's AccessTokenService, it's identified as already being authenticated.

I also asked a question on the CXF mailing list, and got a very prompt reply from a developer agreeing that he'd recently noticed this as a potential issue, and was looking into it. Within a few hours he'd committed a change which addressed it, and looked like it would have been an ideal solution. Unfortunately, I've still not found time to test it, as my solution works and gives me a bit of extra flexibility that's helpful for other requirements on my project.